# How to change container when radio button clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have this layout :

[image]

I want when click on Select Time to change this blue container to another container

this is the code of radio buttons :

```
class TimeRadioButtonsClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeRadioButtonsClassState createState() => _TimeRadioButtonsClassState();
  List<String> labels;
  String picked;
  Function function;
  TimeRadioButtonsClass({this.picked , this.labels , this.function});
}

class _TimeRadioButtonsClassState extends State<TimeRadioButtonsClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioButtonGroup(
      orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
      onSelected: (String selected) => setState((){
        widget.picked = selected;
      }),
      labels: widget.labels,
      picked: widget.picked,
      activeColor: Color(0xffFFD243),
      onChange: (String label, int index) {
          print("label: $label index: $index");
          widget.function(label,index);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and here I call this class in `CheckoutClass` :

```
TimeRadioButtonsClass(picked: picked , labels: when),
```

**NOTE :**  I used `setState` in `CheckoutClass` by access it as parameter in  `TimeRadioButtonsClass`  it changes container for just one time.

I don't know the reason why `setState` doesn't work !

**Edit :** I pass function as parameter to `TimeRadioButtonsClass` (I edit `TimeRadioButtonsClass` code above) and this is the code for calling:

```
TimeRadioButtonsClass(picked: picked , labels: when , function: (String label , int index){
              setState(() {
                   if(index == 1){
                       indexRadio = 1;
                       print("indexRadio 1 : "+indexRadio.toString());
                   }
                   else{
                       indexRadio = 0;
                       print("indexRadio 2 : "+indexRadio.toString());
                   }
              });
       },),
       indexRadio == 1 ? Container(
           height: 50.0,
           color: Colors.blue,
         ):
        Container(
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.red,
         ),
```

Comment: Where is your container, Can you also show code for that, which is you want to change the color for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `container` is outside the `class`, then you can make a `callback` on the selected `button` of the `radiobutton`.

```
widget.onTap(selected);
```

*Add this line of code for the `onTap` method, to make a `callback` to the class from where it is called.*

```
class TimeRadioButtonsClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeRadioButtonsClassState createState() => _TimeRadioButtonsClassState();
  List<String> labels;
  String picked;
  Function onTap;
  TimeRadioButtonsClass({this.picked, this.labels, this.onTap});
}

class _TimeRadioButtonsClassState extends State<TimeRadioButtonsClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioButtonGroup(
      // orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
      onSelected: (String selected) {
        setState(() {
          widget.picked = selected;
        });
        widget.onTap(selected);  //This will make a callback to your class and send the selected value in the onTap method of that class.
      },
      labels: widget.labels,
      picked: widget.picked,
      activeColor: Color(0xffFFD243),
      onChange: (String label, int index) =>
          print("label: $label index: $index"),
    );
  }
}
```

*Now to get the `onTap` value from the `class`, Call your `widget` as below*

**NOTE:** Here value of 1 and 2 is your radio button picked `string` 1 is the *ASAP* and 2 is the *Select timer*

```
TimeRadioButtonsClass(
        picked: "picked",
        onTap: (value) {
          if (value == 1) {
            //do change for one
            containerColor = Colors.blue;

              setState(() {

              });
          } else if (value == 2) {
            //do change for two
            containerColor = Colors.red;

              setState(() {

              });
          }
        },
      )
```

Define a Color for container as Default so to change the color on the onTap method of the class

```
  Color containerColor = Colors.red;
```

Now Show The `container` As Follows

```
Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: containerColor,
    );
```

**EDITED 2:-** (This code changes the color for container and Radio button also changes now everytime)

```
  String picked = "ASAP"; // Add this line at the top
```

Replace the `Code` of Calling `TimeRadioButtonsClass` `Class` with this

```
    TimeRadioButtonsClass(
      picked: picked,
      labels: [
        "ASAP",
        "Select Timer",
      ],
      onTap: (
        int index,
      ) {
        indexRadio = index;
           if (index == 0) {
              picked = "ASAP";
            } else {
              picked = "Select Timer";
            }
        setState(() {});
      },
    ),
    indexRadio == 0
        ? Container(
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
        : Container(
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
```

*And Also Replace the `TimeRadioButtonClass` Itself with this `code`*

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grouped_buttons/grouped_buttons.dart';

```
class TimeRadioButtonsClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeRadioButtonsClassState createState() => _TimeRadioButtonsClassState();
  List<String> labels;
  String picked;
  Function(int) onTap;
  TimeRadioButtonsClass({this.picked, this.labels, this.onTap});
}

class _TimeRadioButtonsClassState extends State<TimeRadioButtonsClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioButtonGroup(
        orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
        labels: widget.labels,
        picked: widget.picked,
        activeColor: Colors.red,
        onChange: (String label, int index) {
          print(index);
          widget.onTap(index);
        });
  }
}
```

*What I have done is that Removed the `onSelected` (maybe it may come use later), and Made the onTap `function` to `pass` the `int` value*

Comment: This solution, logically, should work but it change color for one time and radio button is not moving to second button

Comment: @LailaMattar Please show your full code for relevant files, I will try to look into that and find the issue.

Comment: @LailaMattar I am trying to replicate the issue my side, Can you please tell me which package for RadioGroupButton you are using ?

Comment: I import this package (grouped_buttons: ^1.0.4)

Comment: @LailaMattar I was able to change the color for the container, Please check my latest code, but I didn't use the picked variable, Can you tell me what was it for and what value it contains in starting.

Comment: Okay @LailaMattar I have finally fixed the code and its working fine you can check the EDITED CODE 2.0. It have some minor fixes, that makes the radio button works.

Comment: OMG it works 
thank you so much 
but I don't understand why now it works ??

Comment: Is the reason because of picked??

Comment: @LailaMattar what you have put in your picked variable ?

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` only works within a particular `State` class.

> Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the change in a function that you pass to setState

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

[setState() docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Here, `setState()` is working, but your container isn't in its scope.

When the date is selected, `_TimeRadioButtonsClassState.build` will be called which doesn't affect your container since your container isn't in that widget (or class, if you prefer)

If possible, try shifting the container inside the widget where you'll be calling setState or try using [a different state management approach](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

A more complex approach would be using [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) and passing it as a parameter to your `StatefulWidget` and calling `setState` or using [`context.findAncestorStateOfType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class _TimeRadioButtonsClassState extends State<TimeRadioButtonsClass> {
      String _picked;
      initState() {
       _picked = widget.picked;
       super.initState();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RadioButtonGroup(
          orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
          onSelected: (String selected) => setState((){
            _picked = selected;
          }),
          labels: widget.labels,
          picked: _picked,
          activeColor: Color(0xffFFD243),
          onChange: (String label, int index) => print("label: $label index: $index"),
        );
      }
    }
```